# What part of C#/C++ application can call ntdll!TppIteWakeWaiters method?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winapi, com

I have a C# .NET desktop application which uses COM-objects (native C++). In some conditions the app crashes with access violation exception on the following thread:

```
ntdll!TppIteWakeWaiters+0xa
ntdll!TppCallbackEpilog+0xfc
ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x4ad
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

Of course, I want to debug that. But the question is, what high-level C#/C++ code stand behind this call? I assume, there is something about `Thread` or `Task` .NET classes (both are used in the app).

If it helps, there are also a bunch of threads in the same dump that look like this:

```
ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0x14
ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x300
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

Even though, I found some info about `ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory` call (which means that the thread is idling), I can't find anything about `ntdll!TppIteWakeWaiters+0xa` that fails.

Comment: These are the kind of underlying system calls that are present in many stack traces. Not super interesting in general to spend time on these. Debug with Visual Studio, ensure all exceptions are caught  and wait for it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019#tell-the-debugger-to-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown

Comment: This exception has never been caught as managed System.AccessViolation type of exception. It's being caught as C0000005 access violation even when I debug right in Visual Studio. This is why  I want to know the essence of these underlying system calls

Comment: C0000005 is often a wrong pointer, pointer dereference, buffer overflow, etc.  What's the thread stack when you hit the C0000005 ? Is it only system calls?

Comment: The failing thread (as it's stated in the dump) has only system calls (starting with RtlUserThreadStart and ending with TppIteWakeWaiters). Only if the cause of the error is in some another thread

Comment: A C0000005 in a thread is a buggy piece of code that runs in this thread. What is possible is your native code corrupts the process memory, stack, etc. which makes debugging difficult

Comment: It may be possible, I consider every options now. But for other threads that run native code, it's always stated what dll runs in a thread (after kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14 there goes a call to some specific dll). And there are no things like TppWorker objects there in those threads. This is why I think the failing thread belongs to the managed part, not to the native.

The thing is, I have an access to the native part sources. But it doesn't show the exact place of failure even if I debug right from the native sources.

Comment: TppWorker means that this is a thread pool thread.

Comment: The way the error manifests itself looks a lot like a disagreement between code that assumes an object to never move in memory, and the CLR that loves to shove things around. The only reasonable approach to diagnosing an issue like this is to pull a [Time-Travel Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview) trace, and start digging.

Comment: @RaymondChen got it. But what can TppIteWakeWaiters mean?

Comment: From the name, it's apparently trying to wake up things that are waiting for something. It is internal thread pool bookkeeping. But really what it's doing isn't important. This is some internal thread pool bookkeeping, so a crash suggests memory corruption that is corrupting the thread pool bookkeeping variables.